# How to query data from multiple database and save everything into one CSV file with Powershell?

Tags: sql, powershell, export-to-csv

I have multiple sites and each site has multiple databases like below.

```
# Declare parks and databases list
$parkBGT = "AIT","BGT"
$parkBGW = "BGW","WCW"
$parkSPL = "SPL"
$parkSWC = "APC","SWC"

$OuputFile = "C:\csv\"
```

And here is my SQL function

```
# SQL query execution fuction
function ExecuteSqlQuery ($server, $database, $uid, $pwd, $query) {
    $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
    $Connection.ConnectionString = "server='$server';database='$database'; User ID = '$uid'; Password = '$pwd';"
    $Connection.Open()
    $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
    $Command.Connection = $Connection
    $Command.CommandText = $query
    $dataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $Command
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($dataTable)
    $Connection.Close()
    return $dataTable
}
```

I have several foreach statements to extract the data out from each, here is couple of them.

```
foreach ($db in $parkBGT)
{
    $serverXStore = "BGTSQL07\MERCHPOS"
    $queryXStore = "SELECT
                            'XStore' as Source,
                            business_date as Date,
                            rtl_loc_id as Store,
                            wkstn_id as Register,
                            cast(round(sum(total),2) as numeric(36,2)) as Sales
                              FROM [XSTORE_$db].[dbo].[trn_trans]
                                where business_date = '2020-08-30'
                                --and wkstn_id = '431'
                                --and rtl_loc_id = '41100'
                            group by business_date, rtl_loc_id, wkstn_id;"
                    $dsXStore = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
                    $dsXStore = ExecuteSqlQuery $serverXStore $databaseXStore $uidXStore $pwdXStore $queryXStore
                    $dsXStore.Tables[0] | Export-Csv "$OuputFile $db.csv" -NoTypeInformation
    
}

foreach ($db in $parkBGW)
{
    $serverXStore = "BGWSQL07\MERCHPOS"
    $queryXStore = "SELECT
                            'XStore' as Source,
                            business_date as Date,
                            rtl_loc_id as Store,
                            wkstn_id as Register,
                            cast(round(sum(total),2) as numeric(36,2)) as Sales
                              FROM [XSTORE_$db].[dbo].[trn_trans]
                                where business_date = '2020-08-30'
                                --and wkstn_id = '431'
                                --and rtl_loc_id = '41100'
                            group by business_date, rtl_loc_id, wkstn_id;"
                    $dsXStore = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
                    $dsXStore = ExecuteSqlQuery $serverXStore $databaseXStore $uidXStore $pwdXStore $queryXStore
                    $dsXStore.Tables[0] | Export-Csv "$OuputFile $db.csv" -NoTypeInformation
    
}
```

I am getting csv file for each database like AIT.csv, BGT.csv, BGW.csv, WCW.csv and so on. My question is how do I save all of the results into one CSV file instead of each one for each database? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I’m assuming they have different properties and that’s why you have them in different foreach loops, can you confirm? If so, they don’t belong in a single CSV. How would that even look? Each unique property would be blank for those tables that don’t have it.

Comment: @DougMaurer I figured it out. Just needed to add -Append after Export-Csv for the second, third and so on of each foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add -Append for each foreach loop after the first.

```
$dsXStore.Tables[0] | Export-Csv -Append "$OuputFile $db.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```